# Python unittest mocked method is called 0 times when it's being called at least once

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to assert the mock's methods are called once and expect it to pass. But somehow, the call count of `mock_create_pool`, `mock_insert`, and `mock_close` is 0 and not 1 or more. How can I test that the functions run at least one time?

#### Directory Structure

- src

  - logic

    - main.py
  - tests

    - unit_test_main.py
  - util

    - db_connections.py

#### db_connections.py

```
class DbConnections:
    
    . . .

    def create_pool(self, pool_name="mypool", pool_size=5):
        . . .

    def close(self):
        . . .


class dailyspecial(DbConnections):
    
    . . .

    def dbinsert(self, create_date, data_date, country, confirm_case, confrim_death, test=""):
        . . .
```

#### logic/main.py

```
import util.db_connections as daily

def get_wm():
    . . .
    db = daily.dailyspecial()
    db.create_pool(pool_name="wm_pool", pool_size=5)
    try:
        . . .

        for record in res_table:
            . . .
            db.dbinsert(. . .)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    db.close()
```

#### tests/unit_test_main.py

```
import logic.main as main

class TestWorldMeter(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("util.db_connections.dailyspecial.close")
    @mock.patch("util.db_connections.dailyspecial.dbinsert")
    @mock.patch("util.db_connections.dailyspecial.create_pool")
    @mock.patch("util.db_connections.dailyspecial")
    def test_get_wm(self, mock_dailyspecial, mock_create_pool, mock_insert, mock_close):

        main.get_wm()
        self.assertEqual(mock_dailyspecial.call_count, 1) # pass
        self.assertEqual(mock_create_pool.call_count, 1) # fail, expect pass
        self.assertTrue(mock_insert.call_count > 0) # fail, expect pass
        self.assertEqual(mock_close.call_count, 1) # fail, expect pass
```

Alternatively, I've tried testing the methods by mocking the `util.db_connections.dailyspecial` class only. And it still fails the assertions. Any idea on what went wrong in my mocking process?

#### Alternative tests/unit_test_main.py

```
class TestWorldMeter(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("util.db_connections.dailyspecial")
    def test_get_wm(self, mock_dailyspecial):
        # mock_dailyspecial().return_value = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_dailyspecial.return_value = mock.MagicMock()

        main.get_wm()
        self.assertEqual(mock_dailyspecial.call_count, 1) # pass
        self.assertEqual(mock_dailyspecial.create_pool.call_count, 1) # fail, expect pass
        self.assertTrue(mock_dailyspecial.dbinsert.call_count > 0) # fail, expect pass
        self.assertEqual(mock_dailyspecial.close.call_count, 1) # fail, expect pass
```

Comment: Shouldn't you expect the insert mock to be called multiple times, due to the loop?

Comment: Your last patch is going to overwrite the other three.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ah yes you're right, but it still gives zero

Comment: @KlausD. from my understanding, that's how multiple patchings are done. Do you know how to do it correctly?

Comment: If you patch the module (`dailyspecial`) only, it will be replaced by a MagicMock that creates mocks for the functions automatically. If you need special mocks there you can set them inside the test functions as attributes of the MagicMock.

Comment: @KlausD. I've tried patching only `dailyspecial` and still did not run as expected. I have updated my questions. Please do take a look and see what went wrong with it, appreciate it

Comment: Now I see that `dailyspecial` is a callable. Then you need to use `return_value` on the mock to return a new MagicMock that would become `db` in the code.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not quite sure what you meant, and I ended up adding `mock_dailyspecial.return_value = mock.MagicMock()` or `mock_dailyspecial().return_value = mock.MagicMock()` before the `main.get_wm()`. And it still gives of zero call count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing the `()` when trying to count the number of times, the mock's methods are called. It should be like this instead:

```
self.assertEqual(mock_dailyspecial.call_count, 1)
self.assertEqual(mock_dailyspecial().create_pool.call_count, 1)
self.assertTrue(mock_dailyspecial().dbinsert.call_count > 0)
self.assertEqual(mock_dailyspecial().close.call_count, 1)
```